# CSS menu hover one child element and change and all the other elements in the same time

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a menu... I want when I hover over a `<li>` element to open a dropdown menu and make the other `<li>` elements 50% smaller in the same time only when I hover in a particular `<li>` element. I don't know if I explained it well but here is the code i have done so far and a js fiddle to see it in action... I can accomplish this only with the `<li>` element that I hover but I want to do it and in all other.

HTML code:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li class="a">
           <a href="#">2</a>
           <ul class="hide-menu a1">
               <li><a href="#">1-1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">2-2</a></li>
               <li class="b">
                   <a href="#">3-3</a>
                   <ul class="hide-menu b1">
                       <li><a href="#">1-1-1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">2-2-2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">3-3-3</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">4-4-4</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">4-4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
nav {background-color:grey;width:200px;position:relative;}
ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
li{width:100%;background-color:red;margin-top:10px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
.hide-menu {display:none;position:absolute;}
nav li.a:hover ul.a1 {display:block;}
nav li.b:hover ul.b1 {display:block;}
nav > ul > li.a:hover {width:50%;}
.a1{left:100px;top:39px;}
.b1{left:50px;top:99px;}
.a1 > li{background-color:purple;width:50px;}
.b1 > li{background-color:cyan;width:50px;}
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ELnX5/1/

Comment: This sounds ugly in the extreme but it will require Javascript/JQ to achieve.

Comment: you can get 2,3 and 4 to 50% with the general sibling selector "~": 
nav > ul > li.a:hover  ~ li {width:50%;} 

I couldn't get 1 to do the same.. I would use jQuery for this.

Comment: when you say 50% smaller what do you mean? Text size? width? Height? overal scale?

Comment: You just need javascrpt, no need for jQuery

Comment: @badAdviceGuy I mean the width of the element. Thank you all for your answers. The best answer that suits with my problem is Ruben Verschueren and roastbeef then I'll use javascript as you said because I searched it little more and css can't point to previous elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## how about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ELnX5/3/

```
nav {background-color:grey;width:200px;position:relative;}
ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
li{width:100%;background-color:red;margin-top:10px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
.hide-menu {display:none;position:absolute;}
nav li.a:hover ul.a1 {display:block;}
nav li.b:hover ul.b1 {display:block;}
nav > ul > li.a:hover ~ li{width:50%;}
.a1{left:100px;top:39px;}
.b1{left:50px;top:99px;}
.a1 > li{background-color:purple;width:50px;}
.b1 > li{background-color:cyan;width:50px;}
```

Comment: I edit this a little so to point and in the second element..because like this it point only in third and fourth elements only.